# Is there a way to fine tune the behavior of the Control + RightArrow keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard

I am not satisfied with the behavior of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>RightArrow</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> when navigating the expression in the *Mathematica* front-end. To be specific, they trigger a jump from one command to another. However, when navigating long camel-case commands such as `LongestCommonSubsequence`, I often want to jump from one capital letter to the next and not by a whole command. This is a behavior supported by other code editors when traversing camel-cased commands.

Is it possible to change the behavior of these keys?

Comment: I've been working with this stuff lately.  You can try making the change in the keyeventtranslations.tr file.  If you can't make it work there, then you'll need to delete the control+right arrow there.  And then create a menu command that should take care of it.  If you don't then the keybindings will take precedence over anything you create.